# React: How to fetch Promise Values fetched

Tags: javascript, reactjs, slack

Want to fetch Slack channel information with Slack channel UID that has been stored in Firestore. I use `@slack/web-api`. It's official library supported by Slack.

The Code:

```
// Fetch profile
export function fetchProfile() {
  return dispatch => {
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {
      if (user) {
        usersRef
          .doc(user.uid)
          .get()
          .then(doc => {
            if (doc.data().slack_uid) {
              const channel = new WebClient(
                doc.data().slack_token
              ).channels.list();
              console.log("channel", channel);
               const userItems = { doc.data(), channels:channel.channels);
               dispatch({ type: FETCH_USER, payload: userItems });              
            } else {
              dispatch({ type: FETCH_USER, payload: doc.data() });
            }
          });
      }
    });
  };
}
```

Actually, the channel data has been fetched successfully on the console.

[image]
However, the issue is I can't get only `channels information` in Promise Values. `channel.channels` or `channel[1].channels` is not working. Should I use async? Do you know how to fetch only channel information?

Comment: You definitely don't need async / await. They only help with syntax, it doesn't affect whether or not you can get values. to get your resolved value, use `then(value => ...)` aka `new WebClient(..).channels.list().then(value => value.channels[1])`

Comment: Thanks I can do it!